# Move two or more columns as starting columns in SQL depending on values

Tags: sql, sql-server

| AnimalId | Date | Remark | Number | PA | PCountA | PB | PCountB | PC | PCountC | PD | PCountD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AN001 | 2022-01-25 | LR | 22025002 | coli | 100 | Strep ag | 100 | Strep s | 100 | Staph a | 100 |
| AN001 | 2022-01-25 | 12:10am | 22025002 | coli | 300 | Staph a | 101 | Strep s | 100 | Strep ag | 100 |
| AN002 | 2022-01-25 | 1:50am | 22025002 | coli | 1500 | Staph a | 1100 | null | null | null | null |
| AN003 | 2022-01-25 | 1:20pm | 22025002 | Haem | TNTC | Staph a | 320 | Strep s | TNTC | Strep ag | 100 |
| AN004 | 2022-01-25 | 1:10pm | 22025002 | coli | 50 | Staph s | 400 | Staph a | 100 | Strep ag | 100 |
| AN004 | 2022-01-25 | 1:50pm | 22025002 | 0 growth | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |

I have a pivoted view as shown in the above table. It has Pathogens e.g `PA` found in an animal sample `AnimalId` and the pathogen counts e.g `PCountA`. There are pathogens `Staph a` and `Strep ag` that when found, the pathogen and its result should come first/listed in the first column. For example,in the second row  `AN001`,  `Staph a` under column `PB` and it's count under column `PCountB` should shift to columns `PA` and `PCountA`, i.e it should be the starting pathogen.

In cases where we have both pathogens `Staph a` and `Strep ag`like in the first row,  `Staph a` should start followed by `Strep ag` then the rest.

How do I achieve this in SQL Server?

Note: I tried `CASE` ordering by `Pathogen` before pivoting but it didn't work out.
See below.

```
SELECT  AnimalId, Date, Remark, Number, 
    PA, PCountA, PB, PRCountB, PC, PCountC,
    PD, PCountD
FROM (
    SELECT AnimalId, Date, Remark, Number, Col, Val
    FROM (
        SELECT AnimalId, Date, Remark, Number, Pathogen, 
        PathogenResult,
            CASE 
            WHEN PathogensCount = 1 THEN 'PA'
            WHEN PathogensCount = 2 THEN 'PB'
            WHEN PathogensCount = 3 THEN 'PC'
            WHEN PathogensCount = 4 THEN 'PD'
            END AS PathogenType
            ,
            CASE 
            WHEN PathogensCount = 1 THEN 'PCountA'
            WHEN PathogensCount = 2 THEN 'PCountB'
            WHEN PathogensCount = 3 THEN 'PCountC'
            WHEN PathogensCount = 4 THEN 'PCountD'
            END AS PathogenResultType

            FROM (
                SELECT * FROM (
                    SELECT * FROM (
                        SELECT s.AnimalId, s.SampleDate AS Date, s.SampleRemark AS Remark, o.Name AS Pathogen,
                                CASE WHEN o.RequiresCount = 0 THEN NULL
                                    WHEN sr.NewCount = 999999 THEN 'TNTC'
                                    WHEN t.Name LIKE '%tank%' THEN CAST(sr.NewCount * 10 AS nvarchar)
                                ELSE CAST(sr.NewCount * 100 AS nvarchar)
                                END AS PathogenResult,
                                a.Number,
                                COUNT(
                                    CASE WHEN o.RequiresCount = 0 THEN NULL
                                        WHEN sr.NewCount = 999999 THEN 'TNTC'
                                        WHEN t.Name LIKE '%tank%' THEN CAST(sr.NewCount * 10 AS nvarchar)
                                    ELSE CAST(sr.NewCount * 100 AS nvarchar)
                                    END) OVER(PARTITION BY s.AnimalId) AS CountOfPathogenResult
                        FROM Table_s s
                        INNER JOIN Table_sr sr ON sr.ATSId = s.Id
                        LEFT JOIN Table_o o ON o.Id = sr.NOId 
                        INNER JOIN Table_sp sp ON sp.Id = sr.ATSPId
                        INNER JOIN Table_a a ON a.Id = sp.AId
                        INNER JOIN Table_ag ag ON ag.Id = sr.AgId
                        INNER JOIN Table_ats ats ON ats.AId = a.Id AND ats.Id = sp.ATId 
                        INNER JOIN Table_t t ON t.Id = ats.TId
                        WHERE o.Name IS NOT NULL
                        GROUP BY a.Id, s.AnimalId, s.Date, s. SampleRemark, o.Name, 
                                o.RequiresCount, t.Name, sr.NewCount, a.Number, ag.Name
                        ) as A
                        WHERE CountOfPathogenResult > 0 AND Pathogen <> 'No Growth'
                    UNION
                    SELECT * FROM (
                        SELECT s.AnimalId, s.SampleDate AS Date, s.SampleRemark AS Remark,
                                o.Name AS Pathogen,
                                CASE WHEN o.RequiresCount = 0 THEN NULL
                                    WHEN sr.NewCount = 999999 THEN 'TNTC'
                                    WHEN t.Name LIKE '%tank%' THEN CAST(sr.NewCount * 10 AS nvarchar)
                                ELSE CAST(sr.NewCount * 100 AS nvarchar)
                                END AS PathogenResult,
                                a.Number,
                                COUNT(
                                    CASE WHEN o.RequiresCount = 0 THEN NULL
                                        WHEN sr.NewCount = 999999 THEN 'TNTC'
                                        WHEN t.Name LIKE '%tank%' THEN CAST(sr.NewCount * 10 AS nvarchar)
                                    ELSE CAST(sr.NewCount * 100 AS nvarchar)
                                    END) OVER(PARTITION BY s.AnimalId) AS CountOfPathogenResult
                        FROM Table_s s
                        INNER JOIN Table_sr sr ON sr.ATSId = s.Id
                        LEFT JOIN Table_o o ON o.Id = sr.NOId 
                        INNER JOIN Table_sp sp ON sp.Id = sr.ATSPId
                        INNER JOIN Table_a a ON a.Id = sp.AId
                        INNER JOIN Table_ag ag ON ag.Id = sr.AgId
                        INNER JOIN Table_ats ats ON ats.AId = a.Id AND ats.Id = sp.ATId 
                        INNER JOIN Table_t t ON t.Id = ats.TId
                        WHERE o.Name IS NOT NULL
                        GROUP BY a.Id, s.AnimalId, s.Date, s. SampleRemark, o.Name, 
                                o.RequiresCount, t.Name, sr.NewCount, a.Number, ag.Name
                        ) as B
                        WHERE CountOfPathogenResult = 0 AND Pathogen = 'No Growth' OR CountOfPathogenResult = 0 AND Pathogen = 'Contaminated'
                ) AS C
                ORDER BY CASE WHEN Pathogen = 'Staph aureus' THEN 1
                                WHEN Pathogen = 'Strep. ag.' THEN 2 ELSE 3
                        END, Pathogen
                        OFFSET 0 ROWS
            ) AS ResultsA
            GROUP BY AnimalId, Date, Remark,Number, PathogenResult, Pathogen, PathogensCount) AS source cross apply (
                SELECT PathogenType, Pathogen
                UNION ALL   
                SELECT PathogenResultType,  CAST(PathogenResult AS varchar(45))
            ) ResultsB (Col, Val)
    ) ResultsC
        PIVOT (MAX(Val) FOR Col IN (
                    [PA], 
                    [PCountA], 
                    [PB], 
                    [PaCountB], 
                    [PC], 
                    [PaCountC],
                    [PD], 
                    [PaCountD], 
                    [PathogenE])
) AS PivotResults;
GO
```

**Expected Results**

| AnimalId | Date | Remark | Number | PA | PCountA | PB | PCountB | PC | PCountC | PD | PCountD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AN001 | 2022-01-25 | LR | 22025002 | Staph a | 100 | Strep ag | 100 | coli | 100 | Strep s | 100 |
| AN001 | 2022-01-25 | 12:10am | 22025002 | Staph a | 101 | Strep ag | 100 | coli | 300 | Strep s | 100 |
| AN002 | 2022-01-25 | 1:50am | 22025002 | Staph a | 1100 | coli | 1500 | null | null | null | null |
| AN003 | 2022-01-25 | 1:20pm | 22025002 | Staph a | 320 | Strep ag | 100 | Haem | TNTC | Strep s | TNTC |
| AN004 | 2022-01-25 | 1:10pm | 22025002 | Staph a | 100 | Strep ag | 100 | coli | 50 | Staph s | 400 |
| AN004 | 2022-01-25 | 1:50pm | 22025002 | No growth | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |

Comment: Can you post the statement, that generates the view?

Comment: You need to provide more details. See [mre]

Comment: Without seeing the original query and sample data on which to test it, exactly what are you expecting for an answer?

Comment: @Zhorov I have edited the question to included the original query that generates the view. If it is still not clear, I'd be happy to clarify more.

Comment: @SeanLange I have provided more details and the desired result.

Comment: @Stu I have edited the question to include the original query that generates the view.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are aleady using the idea I had when reading the problem:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Pathogen = 'Staph aureus' THEN 1
WHEN Pathogen = 'Strep. ag.' THEN 2 ELSE 3
```

but according to the output the actual names found in the data are `Strep ag`, `Strep s` and `Staph a` so everything is being sorted with a value of 3.
You could use the following, which would allow some tolerance for future differences.

```
ORDER BY CASE LEFT(Pathogen,5) WHEN 'Staph' THEN 1
WHEN Pathogen = 'Strep' THEN 2 ELSE 3
```

or if you want to rest exact use the following

```
ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN Pathogen = 'Staph a' THEN 1
WHEN Pathogen = 'Strep ag' THEN 2 
WHEN Pathogen = 'Strep s' THEN 2 
ELSE 3
```